# Can not select all by mouse under list view in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I suddenly find this problem when I select "View items as a list" I can not able to select all by using mouse. Is this a natural behavior or that is a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since items are ordered in a list, folder/file data is presented in columns and rows. In a *list*, there is no empty space around the items, and the rows are stretched as far as the right side of the window, so no, it is not a bug that you cannot simply drag to select; you will alway "hit" another item when you start dragging, that is how it should be.

You can of course select items by either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click (to add clicked item to selection) or click / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click (to select a part of the list), but that takes indeed the keyboard.

Comment: My problem was about selecting by mouse. if it's not a bug then I don't have problem by selecting another methods. thanks

Comment: @KasiyA I did not have the slightest doubt you were able to use alternative methods to select, but added it just to be complete