# Is `click & drag` using a mouse still dosen't work in Nautilus list mode?

Tags: nautilus

I was looking for an option to `Left-click & drag` using a *mouse* to select multiple files in `list-mode` of **Nautilus** and came across [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518888/can-not-select-all-by-mouse-under-list-view-in-nautilus). Here, they are saying that it won't be possible, but this post was a couple of years old.

Is it still not possible to select multiple files using `Left-click & drag`? And if it is then how to do it?

I also checked the following links:

1. [List view in Nautilus does not allow dragging a selection by mouse](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/49348).
2. [allow multiple selections with the mouse (and single click)](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138931)

Here, I can see that the problem is not resolved yet.

Comment: If it hasn't been implemented in 14 years the odds are extremely slim to none it will ever be.

Comment: @doug, I was just trying my luck knowing that chances are very less. Thank you.